# Reading in numbers from text file, displaying, then sorting (C++)

Tags: c++, sorting, text-files, infinite-loop, ifstream

Here's the lab objective:
Write a C++ program that retrieves all the numbers stored in a data file.   As each number is retrieved, it is displayed on the screen. After the end of file is reached, the   numbers should be sorted into numerical order and then the the result should be displayed.

Here's my code:

```
int main(){
    fstream infile;
    int numbers[25], size = 0, i = 0;

    infile.open("lab1.txt");
    if (infile.fail())
    {
        cout << "Error Opening File" << endl;
    }
    while (!infile.eof())
    {
        infile >> numbers[i];
        cout << numbers[i] << endl;
        i++;
    }


    size = i;
    cout << size << " number of values in file" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size - i - 1; ++j) {
            if (numbers[j] > numbers[j + 1])
             {
                int temp = numbers[j];
                numbers[j] = numbers[j + 1];
                numbers[j + 1] = temp;
             }
        }
    }

    infile.close();

    return 0;

}
```

It keeps resulting in an infinite loop. Does anyone know why? I appreciate any help thank you

Comment: Ever heard of [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)?

Comment: @JesperJuhl We weren't taught that in class yet, my professor wants us to sort using actual loops and logic by ourselves right now :\ thank you though

Comment: In case the file is failed to open, you just print a message and keep going.

Comment: So what else were you not taught in class that you can't use?  The answer for C++ is to use `std::sort`.  Anyway, 1) [while (!infile.eof()) is wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong), 2) You never checked if there are more than 25 numbers in the file.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie why is the while statement wrong? And yeah I actually realized that I think I should make the array size after I find out the size of the file

Comment: @CPPNoob -- Go to the link I have in my comments.  Second, you never stated which loop is infinite.  Is it the loop where you're reading in data, or the loop where you're trying to sort?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Oh I didn't realize it was a link, thank you I will read that. ANd I believe the first loop is infinite because my output displays a bunch of numbers constantly then crashes

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `i` variable from declaration. Use just the `size` variable.

```
int main(){
    fstream infile;
    int numbers[25], size = 0;

    infile.open("lab1.txt");
    if (infile.fail())
    {
       cout << "Error Opening File" << endl;
    }
    while (!infile.eof())
    {
        infile >> numbers[size];
        cout << numbers[size] << endl;
        size++;
     }

    cout << size << " number of values in file" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < size; ++j) {
            if (numbers[i] > numbers[j])
            {
              //.....
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
char x;
while (infile.get(x)){
    //add numbers to array
}
```

Comment: Can you expand on this answer?